# Unable to add a service reference to SAP in web API

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio

I am using a SAP service to get the data into the web API and then use that web API for the sharepoint client. The thing is when I consumed the SAP service in console application I got the data but when I used the web API it is showing following error 
***'Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'AddonWCFService.SAPService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.'.***
But in web.config I have the end point tag defined. My web.config has following code

```
  <service name="RCWindsSvc.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="RCWindsSvc.Service1Behavior">
      <endpoint address="http://....../SAPService.aspx"
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="RCWindsSvc.IService1"
          behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          name="RCWindsSvcEndpoint"/>
      <!-- behaviorConfiguration="WebBehaviour" /> -->
    </service>
```

Comment: Which web config? You need to have the config entries in the application which is actually running (I believe in IIS in your case).

Comment: You should add more info to this question about what SAP exposes. Don't use “Web API” if You are not even aware of ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: See I have created a web API already now its under the testing phase in which I have to check the  methods. These methods work fine in console application..

Comment: Service extension in your config is aspx. Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: The SAP service is in .asmx format for which I downloaded the wsdl doc. on local machine. Now the thing is how to consume this SAP service in my web API. The sharepoint client won't use the sap service directly. It will use the web API which I'm working on.

Comment: @danish - Sorry for confusion it was .asmx. I'm working on web services first time. :-)

Comment: @LexLi - You have clarified one thing that I can't add service reference to the web API but why the option comes in first place when we right click the references under web API project. If this is true then what approach is better ?

Comment: @danish - web.config of the web API I'm talking about. when I added the service reference then in the web.config the endppoints were created. Now when I run the test then it stops at the first line of code which instantiates the SOAP client of the service.

Comment: Can you put the config section in your share point client instead. I am not aware of Web API so not really sure how that works.

Comment: The sharepoint client is being built by some other team and they have asked me to complete my web API asap and test it as well.